# Disable a page dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've an aspx page and I want to disable that page dynamically on a IF condition.
Here, **By the word 'Disable' I mean an exactly same condition when a pop-up or a Radwindow opens and the Parent page gets disabled and the user is not able to do anything to the parent page until the pop-up gets closed.**

For Ajax or Rad Controls, I can set the 'Modal' attribute of the control to true to make Parent page disabled. But what to do for my required condition.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Check out http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal

Answer (score 1):

You achieve the *disabled* effect by adding a div that covers the page using Javascript or JQuery.

```
var documentHeight = $(document).height();
$("body").append("<div style='z-index: 100; background: lightgray; opacity: 0.5; width: 100%; height: " + documentHeight + "px; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;'></div>");
```

The caveat is that this isn't "secure", if that's what you're after (the user could "hack" the disabling pane using Firebug or similar).

Answer (score 0):

You can use ModalPopupExtender, take a look at my sample. I use this concept in all my sites and works great for all types of browsers.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ConfirmDialogUserControl.ascx.cs"
    Inherits="GP.Solutions.UserControls.ConfirmDialogUserControl" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var _source;
    var _popup;

    function ShowConfirmDialog(source, message) {
        this._source = source;
        this._popup = $find('mdlPopup');
        var displayDiv = document.getElementById('<%= ConfirmMessageDiv.ClientID %>');
        displayDiv.innerText = message;
        displayDiv.textContent = message;
        this._popup.show();
    }

    function ConfirmDialogOk() {
        this._popup.hide();

        __doPostBack(this._source.name, '');
    }

    function ConfirmDialogCancel() {
        this._popup.hide();
        this._source = null;
        this._popup = null;
    }

</script>


<asp:Panel ID="pnlModal" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" style="display:none;">
    <div class="modalHeader">
        <div id="DivImage" runat="server"> </div> 
        <asp:Label ID="TitleLabel" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="modalTitle"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlControls" runat="server" CssClass="modalContent">
        <div id="ConfirmMessageDiv" runat="server"></div>
    </asp:Panel>
    <div class="modalControlsContainer">
        <asp:Button ID="btnConfirmDialogOk" runat="server" CssClass="modalButton" Text=""  />
        <asp:Button ID="btnConfirmDialogCancel" runat="server" CssClass="modalButton" Text="" />
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" behaviorid="mdlPopup" runat="server" TargetControlID="pnlModal"
    PopupControlID="pnlModal" OkControlID="btnConfirmDialogOk" OnOkScript="ConfirmDialogOk();" CancelControlID="btnConfirmDialogCancel"
    OnCancelScript="ConfirmDialogCancel();" DynamicServicePath="" Enabled="True" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" DropShadow="true">
</asp:ModalPopupExtender>
```

Here is css code used in this case:

```
.modalBackground
{
  background-color:Black;
  filter:alpha(opacity=60);
  opacity:0.6;
}

.modalPopup
{
    background-color:White;
    border: 1px solid green;
    width:280px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.modalPopupFullWidth
{
    background-color:White;
    border: 1px solid green;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.modalHeader
{
    width:auto;
    border: 1px solid silver;
    height:25px;
    background-color:#F2F2F2;
}

.modalTitle
{
    color:Black; 
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight:bold;
    position:relative;
    left:30px;  
    top:-20px;
}

.modalImageInformation
{
    background-image: url('information.png'); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    width:26px;
    height:26px;
    border: 0;
}

.modalImageWarning
{
    background-image: url('warning.png'); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    width:26px;
    height:26px;
    border: 0;
}

.modalImageError
{
    background-image: url('error.png'); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width:26px;
    height:26px;
    border: 0;
}

.modalImageQuestion
{
    background-image: url('question.png'); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    width:26px;
    height:26px;
}

.modalImageSearch
{
    background-image: url('search.png'); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    width:26px;
    height:26px;
}


.modalContent
{
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
}

.modalControlsContainer
{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:5px;
}

.modalButton
{
    background-image: url('button-113x28.png');
    background-color:transparent;
    width:113px;
    height:28px;
    border: 0px none transparent;
    color: White;
    font-size:11px;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    text-align:center;
}




.hidden { display: none; }

.unhidden { display: block; }
```